# Encrypt a dualboot-laptop HDD

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, multi-boot, encryption

Windows10 on an SSD has 3 sessions,

- me, admin rights + valuable datas onto an exFAT-formatted HDD
- admin, admin rights + nothing on that HDD (yet still a dedicated user folder)
- guest, nothing on that HDD (yet still a dedicated user folder)

I'd like to add a linux distro to this laptop (ext4 partition into the current NTFS SSD), with the exact same hierarchy, so that the **"me" content on HDD could be only accessed by the "me" linux session.

1) How to make it please?**

Also, I would like the relative for whom I configure this laptop, to be able to hand her device to any repair store or potential fake friend, which would use the admin session to fix stuff.

**2) Is there a way to encrypt the disk so that it's unreadable without some password/key when plugged elsewhere than on the laptop?**

Saw on youtube that TrustedModulePlatform chips exist for computers but idk if it's manufactured for laptops and even whether it fits so...

I know extracting the HDD before handing it to the store solves this need, but she is allergic to getting hands as slightly dirty as when holding a screwdriver unfortunately.

3) bonus question for my personal culture since SOF don't allow us to flood the forum with too many different questions,

 Is the copy clipboard stored on RAM ? Is there a way to encrypt the RAM for the same purpose of not being readable elsewhere than the computer without a password?

edit 4) How to prevent anyone to format a drive?

Comment: Ad. 3: RAM is volatile, once power is removed data starts disappearing within seconds and memory is empty in a few minutes. RAM cannot be encrypted because encryption itself must happen in RAM (chicken and egg problem). The performance impact would be huge too, RAM is a few magnitudes faster than persistent storage and accessed/written to significantly more often.

Comment: You can't prevent anyone formatting the drive - they can always take it out and wipe it, wiping any encryption along with it. Your data won't be revealed but it will be completely lost - take regular backups to mitigate this.

Answer (score 0):

If they can access the machine by booting into the OS then Full Disk Encryption won't work - in Windows anyway they'll be able to access the documents and saved password files, and even inject their own viruses if they wanted to with an admin account. You'll want to use a file-based (not disk-based*) encryption scheme where you have an encrypted container that you keep your sensitive files in, like TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt.

*You can also have a separate disk partition which is encrypted with BitLocker or some other disk encryption (like LUKS for e.g) which holds your sensitive data. Perhaps Veracrypt is supported on both Linux and Windows (I'm not sure - you'll want to use an encryption scheme supported on both though) where you can either access your dedicated encrypted partition, or, access your encrypted container file in your hard drive.

---

If you want a store to not access any part of the drive with physcial access then you *need* FDE like BitLocker - end of story. You, for this reason, may want to FDE encrypt your Windows partition *and also* have a separate encrypted partition or encrypted container on your HDD. TPM's are on many many laptops these days - check the specs online. You may also want to use BitLocker with an external USB to decrypt if you dont have or dont want to use a TPM.

Clipboard is most likely stored in RAM, yes (unless you have clipboard history on, depending on the implementation). Once the computer is turned off or rebooted it loses RAM anyway so an attacker would have to do some clever trickery using thunderbolt or firewire DMA (and a zero-day exploit) with *physical access* while it was running, to even get a hold of it (Or a virus running on your system, but, i'll leave virus mitigation to you :P )

Edit for comment questions:

1)"not having passwords of admin sessions".. What? They wont be able to use any admin password because they wont be able to boot without the BitLocker password or recovery key (which you hold dear to yourself as well as your relative - anyone who is allowed to boot the windows)

2) The linux SSD itself does not *need* to be encrypted but if you dont want then snooping on it (or you dont want them to have the possibility of snooping) then yes, encrypt it using FDE like dm-crypt or LUKS

3)FDE or Full Disk Encryption encrypts all blocks as a whole in one unified encryption scheme - everything, even meaningless system files are encrypted. You cant access a single byte* of the Windows system without the key. Software (well technically BitLocker is software as well but, you know what I mean), or encrypted containers rather, ecnrypt a specific folder or files so anyone can still access the rest of the system, they just wont be able to access whats in that container. Doesn't mean they can't copy it off and brute force it in their own time though, so use a long secure password!

(*OK, boot files are unencrypted but there is nothing useful there - you need it to decrypt the rest of the drive anyway...)

Yes, FDE asks for the password at boot and software such as Veracrypt works on the OS itself and asks to decrypt the container - once decrypted the files are accessible until you re-lock the container. "Every time she opens an mp3" - I can't say, because it heavily depends on the encryption software used.

4) If it has TPM and you wish to use it, it should be available for use when the BitLocker is configured. I don't know that as I only use LUKS for FDE, sorry. This is easily googleable though.

5) When you sleep the computer, RAM is stored but it's not accessible anyway - they'd need to open it and enter your password (most likely) to get your files, and if they take out the RAM stick, power is lost and the data will go very quickly. They'd have to be very quick and use liquid nitrogen to preserve the RAM. No one goes through that effort unless you are dealing with very sensitive info thats very well sought after - in which case you'd probably be tortured for the password instead.
Long story short, I wouldn't worry about the RAM. It's just like if your computer was left locked at the lock screen - they couldnt get in without rebooting anyway and if they reboot, the RAM is all lost anyway. (I'm not including things like DMA ram exfiltration because its very very unlikely and pretty much all OSes have protections against it now)

Comment: if I understand well <br> 1) I need to FDE the Win10 partition so that a thief, not having the passwords of the admin sessions, couldn't use a recovery usb stick to benefit booting on my windows to access the HDD datas ? <br> 2) Does the linux SSD partition needs to be encrypted ? <br> 3) What is the difference between a whole disk encryption and a software encryption ? 1st asks for the password at boot and 2nd everytime she'll open an .mp3 ? <br> 4) Yes her laptop has TPM I checked, thanks! How to proceed then? <br> 5) How to deal with clipboard when my habit is to sleep instead of shutdown ?

Comment: sleep even when I'm away*

Comment: Ive added some info to my answer in regards to your question.

Comment: thank you so much for such answers, allow me though to ask why an FDE of the HDD isn't sufficient ? Assuming I choose to not make her use the TPM and rather type a password at boot, then the repairers can't access the drive, right?

Comment: They can't access the drive but your relative still can, and I thought you wanted to protect your sensitive files against her too?

Comment: oh ok sorry this is a big misunderstanding, my bad, I just named her session "me" so that she knows where to login, but yes all the valuable datas are her and I don't care at all looking at it, i only want the repairers not being able to look at it, so in this case we agree on a simple FDE of the HDD, right ? with veracrypt which is cross platform (luks is only linux I believe) ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I dont know enough about Veracrypt (for exact instructions) but to my knowledge it seems cross platform - Google is your friend. In the same way you may want to FDE your Linux SSD partition too so that they cant read or inject programs into your linux session - but this is entirely your choice and not needed for the valuable HDD data to be encrypted. Linux FDE can be LUKS or Veracrypt (maybe others are available) if you want - you wont be reading that from any other drive, but the Windows one you _will_ be reading from the Linux drive so yes that should be cross platform.